# How to get all materials from a scene in THREE.JS

Tags: three.js, 3d, gltf

I'm importing a .glb model and have in this file some materials that are not applied to any meshes.
So my question is in in THREE.JS exist something like a array of all materials that are in the scene or if I can get some how my materials when load the model with GLTFLoader.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can traverse through the parsed glTF asset and collect all materials in a set. Something like:

```js
const materials = new Set();
const scene = gltf.scene;

scene.traverse( function( object ) {

    if ( object.material ) materials.add( object.material );

} );
```

Answer (score 1):

Mugen87 answer is correct, but material can be array and I think you need handle this specially. And only meshes have material, so I have typescript function to traverse all materials which object have.

```
 traverseMaterials(object: Object3D, callback: (materail: Material) => void): void {
object.traverse((obj) => {
  if (obj instanceof Mesh) {
    if (Array.isArray(obj.material)) {
      obj.material.forEach((mat) => callback(mat))
    } else {
      callback(obj.material);
    }
  }
})
}
```

To store all materials into array you can use somethink like this.

```
const materialArr = Array<Material>()
traverseMaterials(object, (material) => materialArr.push(materail))
```

or you can just remove callback method and push to array directly.